# Including jquery UI in EditorTemplate (ASP.NET MCV 4)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am taking my first steps with asp.net and just created an EditorTemplate for `DateTime?` properties. The Custom Editor is displayed properly, but the javascript code that i included to add a jqueryUI datePicker does not seem to do anything.

This is the code of my EditorTemplate `DateTime.cshtml`

```
@model DateTime? 

@Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToShortDateString() : "no data"), new { @class = "datePicker" , @readonly = "readonly"})

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".datePicker").datepicker(
        {
            showOn: "button",
            gotoCurrent: true,
            showAnim: 'fold',
            buttonImage: "/Images/orderedList0.png",
            buttonImageOnly: true
        }
        );
    });
</script>
```

I am following the examples from ASP.NET MVC Succinctly and took the codefragments from there. Is there something wrong with the way i tried to include javascript?

Comment: Have you included the datepicker JS file in your master page/template?

Comment: Do not do this. Scripts belong in the layout or main view, not in `EditorTemplates`. What if you have 2 `DateTime` properties? You have duplicate scripts scattered throughout your markup.

Comment: And why do you need an `EditorTemplate` anyway (as opposed to just `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.yourDate, "{0:d}", new { @class = "datePicker", @readonly = "readonly")` ?)

Comment: @Rory i added the JS file to the same folder like my Template (`Views/Shared/EditorTemplates`) but i don't see any reference within the code - how does the application know where to look for this?

Comment: @Stephen: thanks for the hint about not using js within templates. For now i just would like to understand how this works - there is no reason not to use the solution you suggested.

Comment: What errors are you getting in the console? Best guess is you have the relevant scripts at the bottom of the page and since you have not wrapped this inside `document.ready()` jquery does not exist when this is rendered

Comment: I edited the code in the question to include `document.ready()`. I tried this before, but removed it again in the question since it didn't seem to do anything. I am not getting any errors at all in the console - I just don't see any effect of the javascript code either. (EDIT: actually this is not quite true - i get some messages like `'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:[...]): Loaded "filepath/System.Web.Services.dll" Cannot find or open the PDB file` )

Comment: @Rory: I just noticed that the jquery-ui-1.8.24 package is included as standard in a MVC 4 application already (it's included in the `Scripts` folder), so the reference to datePicker should be correct.